# How to get endpoint name, method name and fields value from onFailure() retrofit

Tags: java, android-studio, retrofit2

I try to tracking error from all my retrofit, i need to know the name of the problematic endpoint and also the fields submitted by the user

UserServices.java

```
    @GET("visit/current_checkin")
    Call<ResponCurrentCheckIn> getCurrentCheckin(
            @Query("sdo_id") String sdoId
    );
```

My Retrofit Call

```
new ApiClient().getUserService(SplashActivity.this).getCurrentCheckin(sdoId)
                .enqueue(new Callback<ResponCurrentCheckIn>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Call<ResponCurrentCheckIn> call, Response<ResponCurrentCheckIn> response) {
                        if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                            // TODO
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Call<ResponCurrentCheckIn> call, Throwable t) {
                        String message = t.getClass().getSimpleName() + "\n" + t.getMessage();
                        loading(false, message);
                        new LogTracking(SplashActivity.this).save(user, "SplashActivity.java", "GET /visit/current_checkin", t.getMessage(), "Error Backend", null);
                    }
                });
```

ApiClient.java

```
public static Retrofit retrofit;
//    public static final String BASE_URL = "https://online.meval.id/v1/api/";
//    public static final String BASE_URL = "https://v2.meval.id/v1/api/";


    public static Retrofit getRetrofitInstance(String baseUrl) {
        HttpLoggingInterceptor httpLoggingInterceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
        httpLoggingInterceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);

        OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .addInterceptor(new Interceptor() {
                    @Override
                    public okhttp3.Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
                        Request originalRequest = chain.request();
                        Request newRequest = originalRequest.newBuilder()
                                .header("Accept", "application/json")
                                .header("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
                                .header("Authtoken", "MY-AUTHTOKEN")
                                .build();
                        return chain.proceed(newRequest);
                    }
                })
                .readTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .writeTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .connectTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .addInterceptor(httpLoggingInterceptor)
                .build();

        if (retrofit == null) {
            retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create())
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .baseUrl(baseUrl)
                    .client(okHttpClient)
                    .build();
        }
        return retrofit;
    }

    public static UserServices getUserService(Context context){
        SharedPreferences preferences = context.getSharedPreferences(MyPreference.CONTAINER_PREFERENCE.toString(), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        UserServices userService = getRetrofitInstance(BASE_URL).create(UserServices.class);
        return userService;
    }
```

### Question

1. how to get the method name in onFailure()? Example: GET, POST, PUT, etc
2. how to get endpoint name via onFailure()? Example: /visit/current_checkin
3. how to get the value of each field that the user submitted in onFailure()? Example: value from sdoId

I try to use suggestions from android studio when access throwable class but found nothing

Answer (score 0):

```
public void onFailure(Call<ResponCurrentCheckIn> call, Throwable t)
```

You can get a Call object here, and the Call object had a request() method, which will return a Request object, and it has attributes like method, url and body.

```
@Override
    public void onFailure(Call<ResponCurrentCheckIn> call, Throwable t) {
        println(call.request().method)
        println(call.request().url)
        println(call.request().body)
}
```